# Autofill textbox and simulate button click in webpage

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, webview

Im trying to open a webpage and have it autofill the uname and password on completion of the page loading in the webview
and also i am trying to simulate the button click

*web page view source code*

**http://pastebin.com/cEw3VQ41**

the code i am using to do the same is as follows

```
web.loadUrl("javascript:frmLogin.username.value=\"" + mUsername.trim() + "\";");
            web.loadUrl("javascript:frmLogin.password.value=\"" + mPassword.trim() + "\";");
            web.loadUrl("javascript:frmLogin.submit.click();");
```

i have tried ,but it leads to an endless loading loop

```
web.loadUrl("javascript:frmLogin.submit();");
```

username and password is autofilling
but 
**button onclick i am not able to simulate using javascript**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it

using

```
web.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('frmLogin').submit();})()");
```

worked